# Is it possible to programmatically get the server details from an ODBC DSN?

Tags: odbc, dsn

I'm working on some issues with psqlODBC's XA/MSDTC transaction handling and I find myself needing to obtain the server connection details (hostname, port, etc) from any user-supplied dsn programmatically *without* having psqlODBC invoked via the Driver Manager to do so.

Just parsed key/value string pairs will do; the problem is resolving user/system/file DSNs to get the underlying connection info.

The underlying issue I'm trying to solve is that a 32-bit application using MSDTC on a 64-bit system will supply a DSN that works for the 32-bit PostgreSQL driver. The 64-bit PostgreSQL drivers have different names - `PostgresSQL ANSI` vs `PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)` and similar for the Unicode drivers. So a DSN that works for a 32-bit app won't work for 64-bit apps ... like `msdtc.exe`. So I need a way to get the connection parameters the 32-bit app used and feed them into the 64-bit ODBC driver (or direct to `libpq`).

In the case of a DSN-less connection string like:

```
DRIVER={{PostgreSQL ANSI}};SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=5432;DATABASE=SOMEDB;UID=Administrator;PWD=;CA=disable"
```

I could just parse it to get the relevant info, but that won't work for file, system, or user DSNs where the XA transaction co-ordinator used by MSDTC only gets whatever the original user app passed to the ODBC layer - like:

```
DSN=SomeUserOrSystemDSNName
```

or

```
FILEDSN=C:\SomeFileDSN.dsn
```

and wrapped in that DSN is a `DRIVER={{{PostgreSQL ANSI}}`.

I've taken a look at the ODBC API docs and I don't see anything that seems to expose a way to load any DSN string, resolve file/system/user DSNs and get a parameter hash/map. OTOH, there's a *lot* of documentation out there, and some of the sections and function names aren't what I'd call predictable.

So - please tell me I'm missing something obvious, and there's a way to just:

```
GetDSNProperty("FILEDSN=C:\SomeFileDSN.dsn", "SERVER");
```

.. rather than writing hacky code to manually look up each DSN type.